# what is the function in Javascript similar php function substr()

Tags: javascript, string, math, calculator

I have a variable `(var a='10+8-2')`.
Now i want mathematical operation in the string, That means var `a=16` .

Comment: If you want function, `substr` or `substring`. What is the question?

Comment: Your title seems to be asking a completely different question than the text of the question. What does evaluating a formula have to do with the PHP function `substr()`?

Answer (score 1):

javascript has `eval` for this operation

Try like this

```
var a=eval('10+8-2');
```

but eval is evil during minification

Read this before using it

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/4161269